# Outer Regularity of Outer Measure vs Measurable iff Almost Open

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm working through Tao's measure theory notes [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/09/09/245a-notes-1-lebesgue-measure), and am struggling with the following concept:

Let $m^*(E)$ denote the (lebesgue) outer measure of $E$, and let $\varepsilon > 0$.

We know $m^*(E) = \inf \limits_{E \subseteq U \text{ open}} m^*(U)$. 
So we can find $U$ open with $m^*(U) - m^*(E) < \varepsilon$.

We also know that $E$ is measurable exactly when some $m^*(U \setminus E) < \varepsilon$ for some $U$ open.

---

At first glance, this would seem to suggest that every set is measurable - it seems entirely reasonable that we could turn $m^*(U) - m^*(E)$ into $m^*(U \setminus E)$ somehow... Obviously nonmeasurable sets *do* exists, and so there must be no such manipulation.

My insticts want me to try to break this with a nonmeasurable set, perhaps a [Vitali Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set) $V$, but it isn't clear to me what an open set approximating 
$V$ (in outer measure, obviously) would look like. This is probably because of the weirdness that happens with the axiom of choice, where my intuition fails.

---

The question, then is "why does this fail?" What about nonmeasurable sets prevents this (seemingly obvious) manipulation from going through?

**Edit**: 
Somewhat more precisely, what does an open set $U$ with 
$m^*(U) - m^*(V) < \varepsilon$ look like, and why is 
$m^*(U \setminus V)$ *not* small?

Thanks in advance ^_^

Comment: Your seem to make this mistake of thinking that $m^{*}(U\setminus V)=m^{*}(U)-m^{*}( V)$ which is not true. You cannot make $m^{*}(U\setminus V)$ small using the fact that $m^{*}(U)-m^{*}( V)$ is small.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy - I state in the question that I know I have this misconception. Indeed my question is "_why_ can we not make $m^*(U \setminus V)$ small".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another day's worth of thought has led me to answer my own question.

You can build a Vitali set (in $[0,1]$) with full outer measure, whose complement *also* has full outer measure. That is, the open set approximating $V$ is the entire interval $(0,1)$, but $(0,1) \setminus V$ *also* has full measure.

This is exactly the unintuitive behavior that I was struggling to understand.